# How to find the package version that maps to a specific pod version?

Tags: flutter, cocoapods, flutter-dependencies

I'm just starting in Flutter and here's my first Flutter question.
I'm trying to run the Bloc Firebase Login project from the Flutter team.

I suspected that my error was due to a Pod's version problem, so after a bit of research I found out that is due to `GoogleSignIn (~> 5.0)` pod. Now FLutter's `google_sign_in: ^4.0.0` package maps to `GoogleSignIn (~> 5.0)` in `Podfile.lock` in iOS folder but I need version ~> 4.1.1, because more recent versions are for Xcode 11 and I'm on Xcode 10.2.
How do I get to choose what Pod version to use? 
Many thanks for you help.

When I tried changing manually the `Podfile.lock` to `GoogleSignIn (~> 4.1.1)`this was the error in the console:

> [!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod
>   "GoogleSignIn":
>         In snapshot (Podfile.lock):
>           GoogleSignIn (= 5.0.2, ~> 4.1.1)
>
> ```
>   In Podfile:
>     google_sign_in (from `.symlinks/plugins/google_sign_in/ios`) was resolved to 0.0.1, which depends on
>       GoogleSignIn (~> 5.0)
> ```

with `GoogleSignIn (~> 5.0)` the console outputs this error :

> Failed to build iOS app Error output from Xcode build: ↳
>       ** BUILD FAILED **
>
> Xcode's output: ↳
>       === BUILD AGGREGATE TARGET google_sign_in_web OF PROJECT Pods WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
>       In file included from /Volumes/archivi recuperati/Flutter apps/bloc/examples/flutter_firebase_login/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/iOS/OIDAuthorizationService+IOS.m:20:
>       /Volumes/archivi recuperati/Flutter apps/bloc/examples/flutter_firebase_login/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/iOS/OIDExternalUserAgentIOS.h:30:1:
>   error: expected ','
>       API_UNAVAILABLE(macCatalyst)
>       ^
>       In module 'Foundation' imported from /Volumes/archivi recuperati/Flutter
>   apps/bloc/examples/flutter_firebase_login/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/OIDAuthorizationService.h:19:
>       In module 'CoreFoundation' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator12.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:6:
>       In module 'Darwin' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator12.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h:16:
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator12.2.sdk/usr/include/os/availability.h:93:171:
>   note: expanded from macro 'API_UNAVAILABLE'
>           #define API_UNAVAILABLE(...) **API_UNAVAILABLE_GET_MACRO(__VA_ARGS**,**API_UNAVAILABLE6, __API_UNAVAILABLE5, __API_UNAVAILABLE4,__API_UNAVAILABLE3,__API_UNAVAILABLE2,__API_UNAVAILABLE1,
>   0)(__VA_ARGS**)
>                                                                                                                                                                                 ^
>       In file included from /Volumes/archivi recuperati/Flutter apps/bloc/examples/flutter_firebase_login/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/iOS/OIDAuthorizationService+IOS.m:21:
>       /Volumes/archivi recuperati/Flutter apps/bloc/examples/flutter_firebase_login/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/iOS/OIDExternalUserAgentCatalyst.h:28:26:
>   error: expected ','
>       API_AVAILABLE(macCatalyst(13)) API_UNAVAILABLE(ios)
>                                ^
>       2 errors generated.
>
> Could not build the application for the simulator. Error launching
>   application on iPhone Xʀ.

Flutter Doctor outputs this :

> /Users/vinnytwice/Developer/flutter/bin/flutter doctor --verbose [✓]
>   Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.7, on Mac OS X 10.13.6 17G65,
>   locale en-IT)
>       • Flutter version 1.12.13+hotfix.7 at /Users/vinnytwice/Developer/flutter
>       • Framework revision 9f5ff2306b (6 days ago), 2020-01-26 22:38:26 -0800
>       • Engine revision a67792536c
>       • Dart version 2.7.0
>
> [✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK
>   version 29.0.2)
>       • Android SDK at /Users/vinnytwice/Library/Android/sdk
>       • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
>       • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2
>       • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
>       • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)
>       • All Android licenses accepted.
>
> [✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 10.2.1)
>       • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
>       • Xcode 10.2.1, Build version 10E1001
>       • CocoaPods version 1.8.1
>
> [✓] Android Studio (version 3.5)
>       • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
>       • Flutter plugin version 43.0.1
>       • Dart plugin version 191.8593
>       • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)
>
> [✓] Connected device (1 available)
>       • iPhone Xʀ • 0BCA279B-2F3A-4237-84D0-EF6379F7DB56 • ios • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-12-2 (simulator)
>
> • No issues found!

Answer (score 2):

Ok after a bit I thought I changed `google_sign_in: ^4.0.0` to `google_sign_in: <4.0.0` and it worked like a charm. It now maps to `GoogleSignIn (~> 4.0)` in `Podfile.loc`. I guess I'm a bit nervous about dumping Swift and Xcode for Flutter and Android Studio and I didn't see it was a matter of limiting the package version.
Hope it helps others.
Cheers.